# Путь к системным файлам Windows 10 C++

Tags: c++, windows

Возникла небольшая проблема при проверки подписи системного файла. Пришла информация (не важно от куда, но приходит она в таком виде и этого не поменять),  что файл лежит по пути

```
/Windows/System32/browser.dll
```

В Windows 7 x86, к примеру, этот файл там и лежит, а в Windows 10 x64 реальное его расположение такое

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-browserservice_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_5e69b3110728db57\browser.dll
```

Как средствами C++ Из первого пути получить второй?
При чем все файлы, которые якобы лежат в /Windows/System32/ распиханы по непонятным папкам (

Comment: Что значит "реальное его расположение такое"??? `WinSxS` - это системный кэш. Зачем вы туда полезли, если в Windows 10 файл `browser.dll` лежит там же - в `/Windows/System32`?

Comment: нет, он там не лежит. Я бы этого не спрашивал

Comment: https://savepice.ru/full/2019/1/8/6dadfb69e2ccd91d8534c7ee1d29722f-full.jpg.html

Comment: Проводник Windows показывает, что он там есть но, Total Commander  думает по другому, собственно как и программа на C++

Comment: Попробовал `HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\System32\\browser.dll");`. Модуль прекрасно загрузился. Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: я пытаюсь скормить этот файл процедуре https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/example-c-program--verifying-the-signature-of-a-pe-file , но она его не видит... что я делаю не так??

Comment: Что значит "не видит"? Какой именно код возврата вы получили из `WinVerifyTrust`? Что выдает программа?

Comment: lStatus = WinVerifyTrust(
        NULL,
        &WVTPolicyGUID,
        &WinTrustData);    lStatus  = 0x80092003  проверял на файле \Windows\System32\winhttp.dll  подпись у него есть

Comment: Ну уж не знаю... Я могу получить `0x80092003` только введя неправильное имя файла. Для `VerifyEmbeddedSignature(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\browser.dll")` я получаю не `0x80092003`, а `0x800b0100` - отсутствие подписи.

Comment: Только сейчас пришло в голову... а может это быть из-за того что путь выглядит /Windows/System32/browser.dll  , а не C:/Windows/System32/browser.dll  , но ведь на Windows 7 работает...

Comment: Ну так а какой диск является текущим в момент запуска вашего кода на Windows 10?

Comment: я думаю правильнее будет подменять на что-то типа \globalroot\systemroot\system32\